# Why nls (non-linear model) equation in R is different from Excel?

Tags: r, parameters, non-linear-regression, nls

I want to check non-linear model using nls package.

```
power<- nls(formula= agw~a*area^b, data=calibration_6, start=list(a=1, b=1))
summary(power)
```

and this is parameters about the model.

[image]

It says y= 0.85844 x^1.37629

However, in Excel (below graph). It says y= 0.7553 x^1.419

[image]

If I make a graph in R, the graph is the same. Why the same model generates different parameters?

Which equation do I need to more trust? Could you answer me about that?

Many thanks.

```
ggplot(data=calibration_6, aes(x=area, y=agw)) + 
  geom_point (shape=19, color="cadetblue" ,size=2.5) +
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula= y~a*x^b, start = list(a = 0, b=0), se=FALSE, color="Dark Red",level=0.95) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,25,5),limits = c(0,25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,10), limits = c(0,80)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Compare the residual standard error (for R it is shown above) or the residual sum of squares, for R `deviance(power)`,  of the two solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel does not actually do non-linear regression. It transforms and does linear regression.

Let's simulate some data in R.

```
x <- 1:20
set.seed(42)
y <- 0.7 * x ^1.5 + rnorm(20, sd = 0.1)
```

This is what Excel gives me:

[image: Excel diagram with fit]

This is what I get with non-linear regression:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ a * x ^ b, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))

coef(fit)
#        a         b 
#0.7128834 1.4932711
```

This is the Excel approach:

```
fit_linear <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
exp(coef(fit_linear)[1])
# (Intercept) 
# 0.7515136 
coef(fit_linear)[2]
#  log(x) 
#1.471128
```

As you see, same result as with Excel.

Now, which of both approaches is "correct" depends on your assumptions regarding the uncertainty. In the non-linear regression approach you have additive errors. In the linear regression on transformed data, you have multiplicative errors.

See also:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254706/11849

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/255265/11849

Comment: Thank you very much  Roland. Your answer is what I've been looking for so far. Many thanks!! I think this is a stupid question but... if you have to choose one equation, which one would you choose? from  Excel or R? I mean I should explain why I choose certain equation. For example, if I say 'I choose the model, y= 0.85844 x^1.37629 using formula= agw~a*area^b in R', it sounds  logical? Or If I say 'I choose the model,  y= 0.7553 x^1.419 using Excel trend line as power', is that also correct?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. It looks to me like your variance increases somewhat with the mean (although this appearance can sometimes be an artifact of uneven sampling), suggesting that the transform-and-regress approach is probably better. You should also consider whether the difference in lines actually matters to your conclusions (if it does, you should be more careful deciding).